How to prevent ssh access after linux account expiration date?
I was a bit surprised by the fact that a user can still have ssh access to a Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS) where their account has expired.
I set up the account expiration date with chage:
sudo chage -l xxxx
Last password change                    : Oct 10, 2024
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : Nov 05, 2024
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7

The account expired on 2024-11-05, but the user can still ssh to it.
Is there any configuration in the sshd server or PAM to enforce the account expiration?
As far as I can tell, sshd has UsePAM yes and PAM should prevent the login but the only thing it does is to print a  Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator in the ssh banner.
I get the same if I do sudo su xxxx, I do get a Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator but I get the shell prompt anyway.

PAM is a modular system; it entirely relies on configuration in /etc/pam.d/ to define which modules are called and how their results are factored in to the overall result of the PAM call.
For example, each module can be loaded as 'required' where its returned error code eventually has an effect at the end, or as 'requisite' where the error code is an immediate failure return, or as 'optional' where errors from that module are just ignored, or a few other options (see pam(8) and pam.conf(5)).
Expiration according to /etc/shadow data is handled by pam_unix.so in the account (authorization) section of the PAM configuration. If you get the "Account expired" message from pam_unix but it doesn't stop the process, then it sounds like the module was (accidentally or otherwise) defined as optional instead of required.
When sshd handles a connection it uses modules from /etc/pam.d/sshd; when su is run it uses su or su-l. These often include a common /etc/pam.d/system-auth or similar. Go through all those configurations until you find the misconfigured module and fix it to say 'required'.
$ grep -r account.*pam_unix /etc/pam.d
system-auth:16:account    required                    pam_unix.so

Note that the same module in different sections does different tasks:

The 'auth' section handles password checking specifically (e.g. pam_unix verifies passwords against /etc/shadow); this section is skipped for non-password logins like SSH keys.
The 'account' section is responsible for general access control (regardless of auth method), so it's where pam_unix enforces the expiry and lockout checks.
The 'session' section is responsible for session setup, where the same pam_unix module merely logs a useless message to syslog.
The 'password' section handles password changes using the passwd command.


Uhmm, in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I have /etc/pam.d/common-account:account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore] pam_unix.so  I guess the default=ignore is exactly what you are talking about. If I'm reading this right then , pam_unix.so fails , then next is pam_ldap.so and next pam_deny.so. So it means that pam_ldap.so succeeds.

Is that a standard Ubuntu configuration or has someone customized it? It makes pam_unix completely nonfunctional in the account section (on success it skips over 2 modules but most errors are ignored).

I've been looking and no it's not standard, this must be a customization to add the ldap login (incorrectly I guess). I'll try to find a way so that ldap login is allowed but account expiration is enforced.

You can use pam_localuser, which returns success for accounts that are in /etc/passwd, together with the [success=1 ...] syntax to skip 1 module on success; or you can try keeping the current format but changing just the handling of errors – instead of default=ignore you could try user_unknown=ignore default=bad (which is closer to the 'required' template).
